# Why I cannot initialize disk to MBR in server 2012 with the new Server Manager?

Tags: storage, mbr

Why I cannot initialize disk to MBR in server 2012 with the new Server Manager ? just GPT is allowed?

Comment: How big is the drive/volume?  If greater then 2TB, then MBR isn't really much of an option.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware  MBR doesn't support disk greater than 2TB. But what concerns me is that though the disk is only 100GB, I cannot initialize it to MBR format  in the new Server Management in 2012... I think MBR will be eliminated.

Comment: I've seen this, too; looks like they are just silently deprecating MBR. Oh, well, I just don't use that godawfully slow Server Manager anyway...

Answer (score 1):

[When in doubt, use PowerShell](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/san/archive/2012/07/03/managing-storage-with-windows-powershell-on-windows-server-2012.aspx).  In fact, probably better to just use PowerShell by default.  Worst case, you should get an error message to indicate why you can't use MBR with this disk.

---

To initialize a disk as MBR, use the –PartitionStyle parameter. For example:

`Initialize-Disk 4 –PartitionStyle MBR`

---

Answer (score 1):

You can launch the old/familiar Disk Management console by typing:
diskmgmt.msc
at the start - search/launch box, 
It should give you the option to select MBR during the disk initialization.